# Poison Wait Detected: CMEMTHREAD & NUMA - despite enabling trace flag 8048 already

Tags: sql-server

Running sp_Blitz and am seeing `Poison Wait Detected: CMEMTHREAD & NUMA` and 
0:19:10:44 of this wait have been recorded despite enabling trace flag 8048 already.

Running `SQL Server 2014 SP2` in a three node cluster, AlwaysOn AG.
40 Logical Processors, 512GB Memmory.

Got this error a few weeks ago and enabled Trace Flag 8048 but still get the Wait. 
Can anyone please.

Running the following query

```
SELECT
    type
   ,pages_in_bytes
   ,CASE
        WHEN (0x20 = creation_options & 0x20) THEN 'Global PMO. Cannot be partitioned by CPU/NUMA Node. TF 8048 not applicable.'
        WHEN (0x40 = creation_options & 0x40) THEN 'Partitioned by CPU.TF 8048 not applicable.'
        WHEN (0x80 = creation_options & 0x80) THEN 'Partitioned by Node. Use TF 8048 to further partition by CPU'
        ELSE 'UNKNOWN'
    END
FROM sys.dm_os_memory_objects
ORDER BY pages_in_bytes DESC
```

Returns mainly `Unkown` or `Partitioned by CPU.TF 8048 not applicable.`

Can anyone please suggest how to troubleshoot further ?